# Cookies headers sent by an express application deployed in a elb behind a cloudfront distribution are not received in the browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, cookies, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am new to AWS, i deployed a MERN application in it as follows:

1. front end on S3 bucket with web hosting enabled;
2. backend (node, express and graphql) on an ELB;

these two apps are put behind a cloudfront distribution as origins.

the app works fine but a cookie that i am setting is not received by the browser:

[image: response headers received]

the other thing that is bothering me is that the access-control-allow-origin header is set to * although i have the cors policy set in my app to my particular domain.

the cookies are set in development but once i push the code to the server it does not work.

any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work but i am not sure what i exactly did. the thing here is that cloud front doesn't not forward the set-cookie if you don't tell it to do so.

I just needed to update the Cache key and origin requests options that you find when you try to update a behavior like this :

[image]